# I'm having trouble converting text into a tag with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, gridsome

I have a sample text in my div.content

```
These is your very first content with Contentful, pulled in JSON format using the [Content Delivery API](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-delivery-api/ "Content Delivery API").
 Content and presentation are now decoupled, allowing you to focus your efforts in building the perfect app.


## Your first steps

Building with Contentful is easy. First take a moment to get [the basics of content modelling](https://www.contentful.com/r/knowledgebase/content-modelling-basics/ "the basics of content modelling"), which you can set up in the [Contentful Web app](https://app.contentful.com/ "Contentful Web app"). 
Once you get that, feel free to drop by the [Documentation](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/ "Documentation") to learn a bit more about how to build your app with Contentful, in particular the [API basics](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/concepts/apis/ "API basics") and each one of our four APIs, as shown below.
```

I want to get all the strings like this:

```
[the basics of content modelling](https://www.contentful.com/r/knowledgebase/content-modelling-basics/ "the basics of content modelling")
```

from this text and replace them with link a

and insert in a html tags

```
<a href="https://www.contentful.com/r/knowledgebase/content-modelling-basics/ ">the basics of content modelling</a>
```

I am using that regex

```
let pattern = /\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)/gmi
```

Comment: If you create a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and share that link with us it will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern is missing that `()` contains both URL and string in quotes. Add `\s\".*?\"` to your pattern - `\s` matches whitespace, you can omit it if you want to leave space at the end of URL

```js
let pattern = /\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\s\".*?\"\)/gm;

let text = `These is your very first content with Contentful, pulled in JSON format using the [Content Delivery API](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-delivery-api/ "Content Delivery API").
 Content and presentation are now decoupled, allowing you to focus your efforts in building the perfect app.


## Your first steps

Building with Contentful is easy. First take a moment to get [the basics of content modelling](https://www.contentful.com/r/knowledgebase/content-modelling-basics/ "the basics of content modelling"), which you can set up in the [Contentful Web app](https://app.contentful.com/ "Contentful Web app"). 
Once you get that, feel free to drop by the [Documentation](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/ "Documentation") to learn a bit more about how to build your app with Contentful, in particular the [API basics](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/concepts/apis/ "API basics") and each one of our four APIs, as shown below.`

let result = text.replace(pattern, '<a href="$2">$1</a>')

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it wasn't so difficult, I have to learn a lot more.